# Unable to save file with gedit

Tags: fedora, gedit

After upgrading to Fedora 18, I am no longer able to edit the files in my html folder using gedit. The files have the following permission:

```
-rw-r-----. me apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
```

Whenever I tried to save the file, a warning would appear:

> Could not create a backup file while saving /var/www/html/my_file
>
> gedit could not back up the old copy of the file before saving the new
>   one. You can ignore this warning and save the file anyway, but if an
>   error occurs while saving, you could lose the old copy of the file.
>   Save anyway?

I am given the option to "save anyway" or "don't save". But no matter how I click to save it, the warning keeps appearing, preventing me from saving the file.

Since I am the owner of the file, shouldn't I be able to edit it? Not sure why I couldn't do so in this case.

Comment: Do you have write permissions in `/var/www/html`? Can you do `touch /var/www/html/asd` without problems?

Comment: @Peter, ah, so that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be with directory permissions in `/var/www/html`

You should check that you're able to write to that directory so gedit can write a backup of the file your editing.

You can test it with `touch /var/www/html/asd`

Comment: I don't know why those previously set permissions on my html folder are somehow reverted mysteriously.

Comment: Maybe the webserver might have changed them if its run with another user.